# Can't convert object of type java.lang.string to type Friends

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in my application, but when I want to populate my recycler view with data then app crash and I get  "can't convert object of type java.lang.string to type Friends" error. I don't understand what I did wrong here, because I have a user recycler view and I populated it in a same way and I have no problems there. I spent few hours to solve this problem by myself but my efforts brought nothing.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mFireBaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        currentUser = mFireBaseAuth!!.currentUser!!.uid

        mFriendsDatabaseRef =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Friends").child(currentUser!!)
        mUsersDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

       val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Friends> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Friends>()
            .setQuery(mFriendsDatabaseRef!!, Friends::class.java)
            .build()

        adapter = MyFirebaseRecyclerAdapter(options)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        adapter!!.startListening(
    }
```

Adapter onBindViewHolder:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FriendsViewHolder, position: Int, model: Friends) {
        holder.setStatus(model.date)

        val listUserId = getRef(position).key

        mUsersDatabaseRef!!.child(listUserId!!)
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    val userName = p0.child("name").value.toString()
                    val userImage = p0.child("image").value.toString()

                    if (p0.hasChild("online")) {
                        val userOnline = p0.child("online").value.toString()
                        holder.setUserOnline(userOnline)
                    }

                    holder.setName(userName)
                    holder.setImage(userImage)
                    }
                   ....
```

class Friends:

```
ublic class Friends {

private String date;

public Friends(){

}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Friends(String date){
    this.date = date;
}
```

[image: Console screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `setQuery`, you are using the pojo class `Friends`, but in your query:

```
mFriendsDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Friends").child(currentUser!!)
```

You are trying to retrieve an attribute of type String, therefore change the query to the following:

```
 mFriendsDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Friends")
```

Also since your `Friends` class contains a field of type `date`, then you should change your database to the following:

```
Friends
   currentUserId
          date : "date"
   currentUserId1
          date : "date"
```